# Debugging VoiceOver application using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ios7, accessibility, voiceover

I have this huge Web Application using Angular JS. This application run in almost every platform and browser configuration like WIn7/IE10, MAC, iPad iOS5,7 and many more.
But this application does not work well when VoiceOver is ON for accessibility and test on iPad iOS 7. The application turn blank on double tap. How to debug this application and anyone who face similar issue can guide, it will be helpful.

Thanks,
Rocky

Comment: If this is still relevant, could you share a link to the app?